# How to achieve a generic like this?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I want to achieve a generic，as shown below

```
// define
class Zoom {
  values = {}
  addAnimal(animal = {}) {
    this.values[animal.name]= animal.total
  }
}

// use
const zoom = new Zoom()
zoom.addAnimal({ name: 'tiger', total: 10 })

// hint ====>>>
zoom.values.tiger
```

Thanks for any help you can give!!!

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: When posting questions, be specific about the purpose/use of the answer.  "Achieving a generic" is unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please be aware that TypeScript does not track mutations. See [my article](https://catchts.com/mutations).

If you want to infer `values` property, you should return this property from `addAnimal` method.

Consider next example:

```js
type Animal = {
  name: string,
  total: number
}
// define
class Zoom {
  values: Record<string, number> = {}
  addAnimal<
    Name extends string,
    Total extends number,
    Animal extends { name: Name, total: Total }
  >(animal: Animal): this['values'] & Record<Animal['name'], Animal['total']>
  addAnimal(animal: Animal) {
    this.values[animal.name] = animal.total
    return this.values
  }
}

// use
const zoom = new Zoom()
const tigerLiteral = zoom.addAnimal({ name: 'tiger', total: 10 })

tigerLiteral.tiger // 10

// hint ====>>>
const tiger = zoom.values.tiger // number
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggdgSwLYEMA2UC8UDeAoKKOFJCALigGdgAnBOAcwBoCpgB7YdCuAVyQBGEGngC%20eAPQSoAEwgAzehDwBjNCkqUoALXbskuVgDd0vCJQoAlCCvY0ZAHmp1GTIvyE0AfFlzjCKDIy8MjoDqyEAHIk0BAAHsAQcDJazvTMEVAAKpzoUPGJyVp8gsIshIQhqBgFSSm4RDEU0aRuHFxoFDkdUP5QXgAUKIjVFFXoAJQUwAAWCJQA2gDkJmhmlEsAulAAZFDWtvYO42jLxKRbbifL7ehbXqyBwSPoQy%20dsO8ThhVsc5QAOlW6wWw1CaAB5wg22wYOqANuaEyNAgwF4NDgf3mQNM5lY4nEkmkvEoylscGoUAAXnoDNg4BAAO46WkDCaqdgU4BsBAMYQAGQQiRoeWwNP0AKeJwGOEapAoS2AvOESzauQ%20AEYAAy9dl4JV8miC4XoBHKmhQKRQbV4IlQOZwbmYZ2YLxujlcnmG3zipA4tbmM3eq0lTxAA)

[Here, in my blog](https://catchts.com/infer-arguments) you can find more information how to infer literal type from function argument.
TL;DR you should add generic parameter for each value you want to infer

**UPDATE**

```js
type Animal = {
  name: string,
  total: number
}
// define
class Zoom {
  values: Record<string, number> = {}
  addAnimal<
    Name extends string,
    Total extends number,
    Animal extends { name: Name, total: Total },
    >(animal: Animal): this & { values: Record<Animal['name'], Animal['total']> }
  addAnimal(animal: Animal) {
    this.values[animal.name] = animal.total
    return this
  }
}

// use
const zoom = new Zoom()
zoom
  .addAnimal({ name: 'tiger', total: 10 })
  .addAnimal({ name: 'cat', total: 2 })
  .values
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggdgSwLYEMA2UC8UDeAoKKOFJCALigGdgAnBOAcwBoCpgB7YdCuAVyQBGEGngC%20eAPQSoAEwgAzehDwBjNCkqUoALXbskuVgDd0vCJQoAlCCvY0ZAHmp1GTIvyE0AfFlzjCKDIy8MjoDqyEAHIk0BAAHsAQcDJazvTMEVAAKpzoUPGJyVp8gsIshIQhqBgFSSm4RDEU0aRuHFxoFDkdUKLlFV4AFCiI1RRV6ACUFMAAFghaAGQNJmhmFlDWtvYOE2gA2gDkxKSHALpue0ft6Oc%20-lCBwaPowy%20dsO%20ThhVs85QAOlW632I1CaABJwgZ18YOqAJuaEyNAgwF4NDgfwWrHE4kk0l4lGUtjg1CgAC89AZsHAIAB3HRUwaTPCU-SsAFPPaDHCNUgUQ7ABAMYSHNq5D4ARgADL0WYROUFubyoQKVChgGK2BKKAAmOUc4HmPBAA)

[image]
Like I said, TS does not track mutations, hence you need to return `this` from `addAnimal` in order to get some tips

Comment: Thank you so much! ！！And your blog is very useful!  -:)
But your answer is not the answer I want，i mean the property tips showing when i write `zoom.values.`